# How to verify a certificate chain using a CA certificate C#

Tags: c#, cryptography, certificate, public-key-encryption

I am trying to connect to a Mosquitto broker.
The broker will have a ca.crt and a server.crt. My app will only have the ca.crt.

Upon connection the broker provides both ca.crt and server.crt (certificate chain).
How can I validate both against the ca.crt which I already have?
ca.crt and the one present on the client are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`X509Chain`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chain.-ctor?view=net-5.0) class and put the `ca.crt`, loaded as [`X509Certificate2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2?view=net-5.0), onto the `ExtraStore`  property of the [`ChainPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chain.chainpolicy?view=net-5.0) property.

```cs
var caCert = new X509Certificate2(".\\ca.crt");
var serverCert = new X509Certificate2(".\\server.crt");

X509Chain ch = new X509Chain();
ch.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online;
ch.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore = new X509Certificate2Collection(caCert);
ch.Build (serverCert);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work for me. Build return false. However, if I change the order (i.e. add the servercert to the ExtraStore and invoke ch.Build(caCert)) I get true as a result.

I also get the X509Chain from the server (CA cert and server cert which were located on the server). When I Invoke X509Chain.Build(CA Cert from my own station) I also get true.

Is any of the above an acceptable method of validation?
I get the general idea but I don't understand why your code returns false.

Comment: There is a lot of information you can get from the X509Chain which will tell you why it returned false.

Comment: After some reading I changed the following parameters:
1. X509RevocationMode.NoCheck; as I have no way of checking the cert online or using CRL. The cert will be stored as a file or installed in windows certificate store.
2. X509VerificationFlags.AllowUnknownCertificateAuthority; as my cert is self signed.

Comment: So it works - without the online revocation checks - now as I assume. Glad to hear